# Disable a built-in function in javascript (alert)

Tags: javascript, alert, overwrite, strict

Simple: I want to disable/overwrite `alert()`.

Can I do this?

More importantly, is it right to do this?

What about strict mode?

Comment: Why do want to disable it? If you want to override as in you want to have it display html, style it and stuff, you could try using javascript + overlay.

Comment: exactly. In fact, using `alert()` is useless. It annoys both me and the user. I want to override it because a script I use contains it, and I don't want to modify it (and track that modif).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can disable or overwrite `alert()`. No, it's not right to do it, except in some bizarre and limited situations.

Disable:

```
window.alert = function() { };
```

Override:

```
window.alert = function(text) { /* do something */ };
```

Comment: Did you test this? It doesn't work in IE. It has to be `window.alert = ...` in IE.

Comment: @Tim Down - note the `//comment` to to the right of the first js statement.

Comment: I saw it, but it reads as though you're presenting the two alternatives (`alert = ...` and `window.alert = ...`) as being equally good, which they're not.

Comment: @Tim Down, I will rewrite it.

Comment: Why exactly isnt it right to do this? I completely disagree with you

Comment: @Ascherer, overriding a standard browser method interferes with all javascript running on the current page. There are also massive implications with breaking accessibility software like screen readers as well. That's really just the start of the reasons it's not right to disable `alert` like this.

Comment: @jball so depending on what your working on... entirely. If your working on a public site that can have readers that need screen readers, or when using external libraries. I would venture to guess there are more sites online that dont need to worry about either.

Comment: @Ascherer Accessibility is a bigger problem than most web developers acknowledge. I do understand that it's not a concern for *all* sites which is why I said it was right to do "in some bizarre and limited situations."

Comment: i dont think my company's situation is a "bizarre and limited situation". We serve millions of hits a month, we dont need to worry about alert

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can, it's your choice. You could also store the original 'alert':

```
window.nativeAlert = window.alert;
window.alert = function(val){console.log(val+' (alert disabled)');};
```

now the old alert is still usable: `nativeAlert('something');`