# modify insertBefore

Tags: javascript

Is there any way that I can replace the insertBefore and similar with my own functions. My aim is to implement an undo feature and if I'm able to implement it this way, I wont have to change each instance of insertBefore in my code with my function name and it would also make the further development easier.

I've found something similar here [Disable a built-in function in javascript (alert)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343255/disable-a-built-in-function-in-javascript-alert) but am not able to figure out how to use it in my case because I dont know who is the parent of these functions (insertBefore,appendChild etc).

I just want to insert one line of my code and then call the native code.

Please advise

PS. I'm trying to implement an undo functionality and this library requires me to register an undo in that undo-function for allowing redo. So all I want to do is make that a single line of code is always executed before any insertBefore and similar functions.

I'm not talking about any libraries, but just the plain ECMAscript.

Comment: Some example code would help us. What line do you want to insert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about the [insertBefore](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-952280727) method of the Node interface, then whether you can or can't do is really moot. The important thing is that you shouldn't. It is a method of a host object and should be left alone.

Incidentally, the term *built-in* is normally used for the built-in objects and methods of ECMAScript. The *window.alert* method is more correctly described as a *method of a host object* and really shouldn't be tampered with either (although in general it can be).

Comment: Could you explain why it shouldn't be tampered with. Is it because it could affect the rest of the page accidentally?

Comment: Would it be OK to add similar functions such as insertBefore_mine to the prototype of Node instead of replacing the originals?

Comment: I took your advice and implemented a separate interface for the DOM operations but I would still love to know the reason for your advice.

Comment: Host objects are a law unto themselves, they have defined interfaces but not implementation. Kangax has a good explanation of [why host objects should not be extended](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/). Even in a closed or controlled environment, depending on features of particular implementations may limit future choices of user agents, so not a good idea even then.