# Is it possible to overwrite window.location function with a custom function?

Tags: javascript, function, replace, built-in

Is it possible to disable, or even better, replace with a custom function, `window.location`?

This question is related: [Disable a built-in function in javascript (alert)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343255/disable-a-built-in-function-in-javascript-alert)

While it works quite well for `window.alert`, this does not work for `window.location`.

We would love to be able to find a way to replace or disable (replace would be ideal, so we can AJAX log) `window.location`... Dirty advertisers have at times before used this to steal people away from our web properties.

Any ideas?

Even something that only works on a few specific browsers would be fine as once caught (via AJAX logging) we can act on this fairly quickly.

Comment: `window.location` is not a function.

Comment: from chrome console:

    console.log(typeof window.location);
    object

one step closer i suppose.

any idea if what i am trying to accomplish is possible?

Comment: @anonymous-one: Nope -- it's a property, so you cannot replace it with your own code (there is no code to replace).

Comment: Are you saying that advertisers are changing the window.location property in your web pages, and thus directing users away from your site to a different one?

Comment: it has happened twice in the last 1.5 years (that we know of). we iframe all of our adspaces, but they were able to get around this via parent.window.location=....;

Comment: Hmm, interesting problem, but I don't have an answer.  Maybe this SO question is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073086/javascript-how-to-intercept-window-location-change

Comment: i would like to mention that after trying different ways, inculding the _defineGetter_ methods in the answer below... replacing the window.location object does not appear to be possible... even with the latest browsers (chrome 12, ff4+, ie9, etc)... too bad :(:( we even tried methods like: window.onebeforeunload=function(){console.log(window.location);}... no dice :(

Comment: @Jon how the hell they are changing `window.top`  and pretending that the ads are shown on different site??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe you can reassign `window.location`. From **MDN**:

> **Summary**
>
> Returns a Location object, which
>   contains information about the URL of
>   the document and provides methods for
>   changing that URL. *You can also assign
>   to this property to load another URL*.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

As it takes a value like a property, how would you "reassign" the object/function to another value? I don't think it's possible due to the property behavior.

Comment: after much effort, we have come to the realization that the behavior of window.location cannot be altered.

Comment: @anonymous-one - That's a bummer. I haven't ever seen ad networks that hijack a page, so I hope you can figure something out. Can you whitelist the ads that will show up on your site?

Comment: It is possible to use `__defineGetter__` to override window.location in some browsers although I don't recommend it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__

Comment: At least in chrome and firefox it is not possible since window.location is not configurable

Comment: In regards to @dansomething comment, here is a solution: https://gist.github.com/zacharytamas/082e538784ebe07e40f9

Comment: @MLM what about `window.top` ??

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
var _window = {
       location: "myLocation"
};

(function (window) {
   console.log(window.location);
}(_window));
```

Comment: This may not help if you're purely iframing a site, but it was totally useful for my case. Thanks!

Comment: It creates a variable that when passed to a function mimics the `window.location` property locally. It doesn't affect the global `window.location` property though