# Know the URL written in "location.href" before user is getting redirected there

Tags: javascript, redirect

Is there any way to get the URL written with **location.href** into **window.onbeforeunload** function?

I want to include some 3rd party js into my website. Some of them might have redirection code inside of it something like this:

```
location.href="http://example.com";
```

So, it will cause a redirection to their website when user try to open my website. So I just want to prevent it. I can do that using:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    // Here I want to get the URL where user is going to be redirect
    // If that URL is a 3rd party website, I will return false 
    return false;
}
```

As per my knowledge, it is something like impossible.

Any help would be appreciated.

**PS:** I already checked this: [How can i get the destination url in javascript onbeforeunload event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686687/how-can-i-get-the-destination-url-in-javascript-onbeforeunload-event)

So here simply, I just want to prevent such automated 3rd party redirection. Is there any **code/tool/script** available for that?

Thanks,
Parth vora

Comment: If you can't trust a third party library to not mess with your page in ways you don't intend I have to ask if it's a good idea to use that library.... This is mostly possible if you override the location property itself.

Comment: @Gerrit0, ok so how can I override location property?

Comment: Sorry, looks like I was somewhat wrong about this... it may be somewhat possible to override, but there is no clean solution... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478617/is-it-possible-to-overwrite-window-location-function-with-a-custom-function