# Can parent.location be trusted?

Tags: javascript, iframe, browser, cross-domain, client-side

This question treats about javascript code running in a browser (client-side).

Say I know I am in an iframe, can I trust `window.parent.location` or `document.referrer` to actually be the true url of the parent of my iframe?

In other words, assuming that the user's browser does a correct job of following CORS specifications, could `evil.com` iframe my page in such a way that `window.parent.location` or `document.referrer` is not `evil.com` ?

Comment: So you delete the one and make another?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: As stated in the question you deleted... You can not even be sure it is a browser

Comment: He does say *assuming that the user's browser does a correct job of following CORS specifications*, which seems like a reasonable assumption to me. I'd be pretty confident that the properties you refer to are trustworthy, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @epascarello if it's not a browser, it probably isn't an authenticated user either. This question is not about protecting me from "not a browser" scenarios, but from evil websites iframing my page, pretending to be other websites

Comment: @Sinder not hard to get cookies and send it

Comment: @epascarello I am not in a server-side scenario (as the other question seemed to imply), and I do not want to prevent iframing in a not-same-origin scenario.

Comment: I am not sure how a they would fake the parent.location..... You are talking about altering the browser.... Whitelist domains and trust the browser

Comment: I want to know if parent.location could be faked by the parent of an iframe. I'm pretty sure it could be faked by an altered browser

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location is read only https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478617/is-it-possible-to-overwrite-window-location-function-with-a-custom-function