# Can we run event when location.search called

Tags: javascript

I am asking if i can launches `debugger` event
If any function calls `location.search`

Instead of search on `location.search` and set breakpoint on it

Comment: Are you trying to intercept third-party scripts using this? Or your own? If they're your own, you'd be better off using your own custom location and setting the debugger there

Comment: I am trying on third-party scripts

Comment: You cannot overwrite it for third-party scripts https://stackoverflow.com/a/6478728/989920 - AFAIK, overwriting location is the only way to inject a debugger, since it is not an event