# A quest to prevent `window.location.reload()` before `load`

Tags: javascript

So this is more of a curiosity, rather than a problem I'm facing. I've come across a website that calls `window.location.reload()` before the `load` event fires. How would you break out of this refresh loop, as a user? Can it even be done?

Anyways, I've tried the following:

#### Replacing `window.location.reload` (via greasemonkey)

This is not possible since [`window.location` is read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6478728).

#### Listening for `window.onbeforeunload` and hitting cancel (via greasemonkey)

The reload call happens before the document loads. This means the `beforeunload` event is never fired due to lack of [transient activation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/User_activation#transient_activation), so there's no prompting for you to cancel the reload.

#### Block JavaScript (or: block all network requests)

This *does* disable the reload. And also the entire site, so it's not ideal.

#### Block the request to the specific file with the reload call (via devtools)

Same as above, since the file in question is a Webpack bundle, containing the majority of the site's functionality.

#### Inject a userscript that replaces the function calling `windows.location.reload()` with an equivalent function that doesn't call `windows.location.reload()` (via greasemonkey)

I don't think it's possible for this site. Webpack loads every function in an IIFE, so it's not obvious how to modify the function in question before it gets passed as a callback and becomes untouchable. In any case, this approach doesn't generalize.

#### Place a breakpoint at the `window.location.reload` call, and modify some local function to throw an error before it can call reload (via devtools)

This didn't work (on Firefox, at least) -- try it out, `(function() {throw new Error(), window.location.reload()})()`. Due to the comma operator, it'll reload despite the thrown error, and every Webpack expression seems to be a string of comma-separated statements so there's no avoiding this. This approach also doesn't generalize.

#### Manually modify the construction of the global Webpack `window.webpackChunk_N_E` table (via greasemonkey)

I don't know about modern Webpack to know if this could be done, but I tried replacing the particular method in question in that table with a `()=>{}`. It didn't work -- I believe the method was already passed as a callback before the tire change. We are dealing with a function that is far too powerful to care about its replaced reference in some mere global table.

#### Close the tab

I gave up.

Did I miss anything obvious, or is it impossible by design to break this particular kind of refresh loop in the browser (short of disabling JavaScript)?

Comment: By the way, the site in question is the esteemed walmart.com -- if you lack session cookies, it does the honor of baking you some cookies for a guest session, and helpfully refreshes the page afterwards. Oh, you're blocking session cookies? That's a refresh loop! Anyways, I'm not concerned with making Walmart work -- just curious how one would break this particular kind of refresh loop in general.

Comment: Can't you just enable cookies to do whatever you need to do, then disable them?

Comment: @Samathingamajig Yeah, that's the way to go if I wanted to shop, but I'm reaching out here to ask about the limits of modern browser technology.

Comment: Based on the info provided here, you'd need to intercept and modify the webpack bundle (or just replace it with your own js) or modify your browser (the actual code of the browser, not a userscript).