# Is there an "all alerts off" script that will disable all alerts?

Tags: javascript, prototype, alert

Suppose I use a lot of alerts during troubleshooting and rather than go back through and remove them all, I would just rather turn them all off? Can it be done? Maybe by re-writing the `alert.prototype?

Comment: That's this question?! But it is a duplicate, e.g. of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343255/disable-a-built-in-function-in-javascript-alert?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need something like:

```
var oldAlert = window.alert;

window.alert = function(){
   if (enableAlertFunction){
      oldAlert.apply(window,arguments);
   }
}
```

`enableAlertFunction` is to toggle on/off all your `alert`. Remember to run this code first before all the code on your page.